# Install JRE-6 (Mac) for IntelliJ but alongside JRE-8

Tags: intellij-idea

I have just purchased a new MacBook Pro with Yosemite. Yosemite does not ship with any Java runtime. So I have now installed JDK-8 and JRE-8. However, I need to install Java-6 runtime for IntelliJ. How can I install it alongside the JRE-8 and then point IntelliJ to use 6 but keep all mac java home as version 8?

Thanks

Comment: because it can't run under 7 or 8. see: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363

Comment: That's pretty scary.  Java 6 is past End Of Life at this point.  It's no longer supported with security updates so you really shouldn't be using it.  In theory, you can install JDK6 alongside 7 or 8 without any issues, but I'd think long and hard before running any software that required me to install EOL software that can open my system up to security issues.